# Is webform_civicrm 7.x-5.1 compatible with Drupal 7.67 and CiviCRM 5.19?

Tags: webform-civicrm

In the module update page in Drupal, it is shown as not compatible.

If so, what is the minimal configuration for webform_civicrm 7.x-5.1?
(I will update Drupal soon, but in the meantime, I prefer to update the module, if possible)

Comment: Where does it say it's not compatible? If there is something confusing on the drupal project page - let me know and I'll edit it. BTW you will want to run Drupal Security Updates -> to Drupal 7.72 as well as CiviCRM Security Updates... (5.24.x and on Aug 19 -> 5.28.x)

Answer (score 2):

I dont see any thing on module page that it says not compatible with 7.67 and Civi 5.19. The minimum requirement for 5x is CiviCRM 5.12+ and you are on 5.19. So i dont see any reason why it wont support.

Comment: thanks Pradeep, that's also what I read and thought. I'll update safely.